# SQL Query Return 0 on weeks in between

Tags: sql-server-2016

i have this query that works , but the result is not like i want

returns only year and weeks that has data , i want to return 0 to the result

for example this returns

```
year    week   totalstop
2017    50     7
2018    1      3
2018    3      5
```

but i want to return

```
year    week   totalstop
2017    50     7
2017    51     0
2017    52     0
2018    1      3
2018    2      0
2018    3      5
```

and so on

here is the current query

```
SELECT year(Stopdate)[year],datepart(week,date1) [week],sum(stop) totalstop 
        from Table1 where 
        building in (select item from dbo.fn_Split('A1,A2,A3,A4,A5',',')) 
        and 
        date1 between '2017-12-12' and '2018-05-08' 
        and grp = 1
        group by year(date1),datepart(week,date1)
        order by year(date1),[week]
```

iam using ms sql-server 2016

need help to modify it to my needs as iam out of ideas atm.

Comment: Source data? We have only output data

Comment: Don't you need to JOIN to a calendar table if the missing rows don't have data

Comment: any example on that , quite new to sql so still learning.

Comment: @UlrikSvensson Here's a link on how to create a calendar table along with the benefits of one https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/